# npm mysql2: Too many connections when using promises and a connection pool

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, es6-promise, mysql2

Using the mysql2/promise module, I'm creating a connection pool like this:

```
import mysql from 'mysql2/promise';

async function getConnection() {
    let pool = await mysql.createPool({
        connectionLimit: 10,
        host:'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        database: 'customers'
    });

    return pool.getConnection();
}

export  {
    getConnection
};
```

In another file, I am access this functionality like this:

```
import {getConnection} from '../config/database/mysql';

async function getCustomerAddresses(id){
    let conn = await getConnection();

    let [rows, fields] = await conn.execute(
        `SELECT *
        FROM addresses WHERE customer = ?`, [id]);

    conn.release();

    return rows;
}
```

After calling the function a couple of times, I'm getting the following error:

**Too many connections**

What am I doing wrong? And is there a more elegant way so I don't have to include the getConnection() call in every function?

Answer (score 5):

You are creating new pool each time you want new connection, and though pool is eventually is GCed connection is still open unless you manually call `.close()` on it. What you should really do is to have one single pool  and it will manage connections lifetime for you:

```
import mysql from 'mysql2/promise';

const pool = mysql.createPool(params);  
const getConnection = () => pool.getConnection();
export { getConnection }
```

Comment: When I do this `await getConnection.execute('SELECT * FROM sheet)` I got eror getConnection is not a function

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience, I believe that your problems is this code

```
conn.release();
```

In my case, I changed it to

```
conn.destroy();
```

I just read the documentation and I think the difference is explained in the documentation by this:

> Connections are lazily created by the pool. If you configure the pool
>   to allow up to 100 connections, but only ever use 5 simultaneously,
>   only 5 connections will be made. Connections are also cycled
>   round-robin style, with connections being taken from the top of the
>   pool and returning to the bottom.

Whereas destroy is this

> This will cause an immediate termination of the underlying socket.
>   Additionally destroy() guarantees that no more events or callbacks
>   will be triggered for the connection.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, there's an even more elegant way by using `pool.promise()`.

```js
import mysql from 'mysql2';

const pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    database: 'users',
});

const asyncPool = pool.promise();

export default asyncPool;
```

That async pool can then be queried using `async/await` like this:

```
const [row] = await pool.query(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE uname = ?;`, ['john']);
```

Comment: This is a great way to go, don't have to release or destroy connections, let the pool handle it.